# Virtuemart 2: simplifying ordering

Tags: virtuemart

How I can **disable confirmation of order**? I want go to cart, fill some areas and buy product without second page with all this data - only for confirmation - it looks like I press F5. It is default behaviour of Virtuemart.

I google for two days and found some answers, but no one work for me - maybe new version of Virtuemart have some changes.

Or maybe someone know free one-page-checkout plugin?

And I can't set **default values for radiobuttons with only one value** - anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: There is no Free one Page checkout template for VM Now , take a look at this http://demos.virtueplanet.com/opc/light/style-1/index.php(Paid)

Comment: Error on this page: 404

Comment: sorry the (paid comes with the link) http://demos.virtueplanet.com/opc/light/style-1/index.php/en/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtuemart 3.0.10 disable double confirmation on checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785533/virtuemart-3-0-10-disable-double-confirmation-on-checkout)