# virtuemart 3.0.10 disable double confirmation on checkout

Tags: checkout, virtuemart

There is solution.
In my sites on virtuemart I manually (with code editing) do one page checkout (and one step). But after version 3.0.10 my solution no longer work.

**Before version 3.0.10 I used follow method:**
In cart/tmpl/default.php in bottom of file  present hidden inputs.
After `<input type='hidden' name='task' value='updatecart'/>`
add `<input type='hidden' name='task' value='confirm'/>`. And it works.

But **after version 3.0.10** I found no other option except hack of virtuemart core:
In cart/tmpl/default.php in bottom of file  present hidden inputs.
Del `<input type='hidden' name='task' value='updatecart'/>`
add `<input type='hidden' name='task' value='confirm'/>`.
In site/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/cart.php
in method display() change

```
if(($task == 'confirm' or isset($request['confirm'])) and !$cart->getInCheckOut()){
$cart->confirmDone();
```

to

```
if(($task == 'confirm' or isset($request['confirm'])) and !$cart->getInCheckOut()){
$cart->checkoutData(false);
$cart->confirmDone();
```

---

My English is bad, but hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for hacks anymore. VirtueMart 3.0.10 doesn't have double confirmation. Just check "OPC" and "Ajax for OPC" in the VirtueMart configuration - tab "checkout".
If you have chosen shipping and payment and checked the TOS button, the "Check Out Now" button switches to "Confirm Purchase". 
One click and it is done.

Best practise will be to delete your old overrides and use the original VirtueMart files. Apply any custom changes to the new original files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe it work in totally clear VM without customizes.
In my case it not work. I remove all overrides from my /tmpl/cart/ and try.
I have shopperfields in cart and if I left them blank and press checkout, I moved to other page to fill them (why walidation of not empty not work)(this way is not for me - I want one page checkout). If I fill them and press checkout then opened the cart with a proposal to confirm checkout.

Comment: If you want a proper one page checkout, you have to go for an extension. There are different ones on the market, VirtuePlanet and Rupostel work best from my experience. If there are problems with the shopperfields, check if they are mandatory in the VM config.

Comment: it's a very bad solution, like all vm=) why must i install OPC.  it not install by default  =)